# Serving different webflux endpoints on different eventloops

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, kotlin, spring-webflux

I have ported a large spring-web codebase to spring-webflux. There two sets of endpoints, some critical endpoints that must be fast, and some others that are not vital if they end up blocking in production. I can validate that none of the critical endpoints block on the eventloop thread, but validating all the other endpoints is not feasible. I would like to run them on a different threadpool or eventloop, so if they block, they do not affect the critical endpoints.

How would I go about this?

I've tried using reflection to find all the handlers that either should or shouldn't be on a secondary eventloop, but can't think of a way to assign them to it. Alternatively, is it possible to run both spring-web and spring-webflux, and have spring-web serve the non-critical endpoints?

I've managed to get the handlers from the handler registry like so:

```
@Component
class HandlerFinder(val requestMappingHandlerMappings: List<RequestMappingHandlerMapping>) {

    @PostConstruct
    fun start() {
        for (rmhm : RequestMappingHandlerMapping in requestMappingHandlerMappings) {
            val handlerMethods: Map<RequestMappingInfo, HandlerMethod> = rmhm.handlerMethods

            for ((mapping, method) in handlerMethods) {
                for (urlPattern in mapping.patternsCondition.patterns) {
                    log.info("${method.beanType.name}#${method.method.name} <-- ${urlPattern}")
                }
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HandlerFinder::class.java)
    }
}
```

I think the next step would be to somehow change the handlers to be wrapped in something like below, but I'm not sure how to change this in the handler registry:

```java
Mono.fromCallable(() -> { ... handler method goes here ...}).publishOn(Schedulers.elastic());
```

I know I can unregister the mapping with `rmhm.ungreisterMapping(mapping)` and then re-register it with something like `rmhm.registerMapping(mapping, method.bean, method.method)`, but I'll need to create new methods to wrap the existing ones somehow.

Answer (score 1):

my suggestion would be to take your critical endpoints, that you dont want blocking and set `subscribeOn`

as the [documentation](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/reference/#_the_publishon_method) states for `subscribeOn`

> Changes the Thread from which the whole chain of operators subscribes

Your choice `publishOn` will only change the context from where that has been declared, and forward. `subscribeOn` will set an entire subscription to a dedicated scheduler.

This way you can split up how you want your endpoints should be handled on different schedulers internally in the application.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by creating a WebFilter and changing `subscribeOn` as Thomas' answer suggests.

```
@Component
class SchedulerWebFilter(): WebFilter {
    val executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(32)
    private val pathsWhitelist: Set<String> = ...

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        val path = exchange.request.path.toString()
        return if (!pathsWhitelist.contains(path)) {
            chain.filter(exchange).subscribeOn(Schedulers.fromExecutor(executorService))
        } else {
            chain.filter(exchange)
        }
    }
}
```